# Mac OS X XPC as IPC between two applications

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xpc

I have a windowed application and windowless helper, sitting inside the app bundle, and working as login item. App can start and stop the helper, everything woks there. The problem is that I need to create some bidirectional communication channel between them. And it should work in both sandboxed and not sandboxed versions, desirably in OS X 10.7+.
I've investigated the topic and find that XPC can provide peer-to-per connection. I've read related Apple docs, as well as few topics below:

[Is possible to use Mac OS X XPC like IPC to exchange messages between processes? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637206/is-possible-to-use-mac-os-x-xpc-like-ipc-to-exchange-messages-between-processes)
[Communicate with another app using XPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040765/communicate-with-another-app-using-xpc)
http://afewguyscoding.com/2012/07/ipc-easy-introducing-xpc-nsxpcconnection/
https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/xpc/

But I can't find any description of how should I organize my XCode project. I have two targets: "Main App" and "Helper App". Now I need to add the third one, taking XPC Service, as a template. OK, but what to do next? Where this XPC bundle should be located to be available for both applications? Note, that helper sits in the main app bundle, as it's a login item. So, I need some clear instruction or just a XCode project sample.

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: I'm working on this now actually-- have you made any progress?  My current strategy is to create two XPCServices, one for each app.  Then finding a way for the services to communicate with each other?  It's a stretch, but I'm pretty convinced at this point it's not possible to directly communicate from one app to another.  I believe there has to be an XPCService in between

Answer (score 11):

Alright for anyone that has been struggling with this, I was finally able to 100% get communication working between two application processes, using `NSXPCConnection`

The key to note is that you can only create an `NSXPCConnection` to three things.

1. An XPCService.  You can connect to an XPCService strictly through
   a name
2. A Mach Service.  You can also connect to a Mach Service
   strictly through a name
3. An `NSXPCEndpoint`.  This is what we're
   looking for, to communicate between two application processes.

The problem being that we can't directly transfer an `NSXPCEndpoint` from one application to another.

It involved creating a machservice Launch Agent ([See this example for how to do that](https://github.com/brenwell/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample)) that held an `NSXPCEndpoint` property.  One application can connect to the machservice, and set that property to it's own `[NSXPCListener anonymousListener].endpoint`

Then the other application can connect to the machservice, and ask for that endpoint.

Then using that endpoint, an `NSXPCConnection` can be created, which successfully established a bridge between the two applications.  I have tested sending objects back and forth, and it all works as expected.

Note that if your application is sandboxed, you **will** have to create an `XPCService`, as a middle man between your Application and the Machservice

I'm pretty pumped that I got this working-- I'm fairly active in SO, so if anybody is interested in source code, just add a comment and I can go through the effort to post more details

**Some hurdles I came across:**

You have to launch your machservice, these are the lines:

```
   OSStatus                    err;
   AuthorizationExternalForm   extForm;

   err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, NULL, 0, &self->_authRef);
   if (err == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
      NSLog(@"SUCCESS AUTHORIZING DAEMON");
   }
   assert(err == errAuthorizationSuccess);

   Boolean             success;
   CFErrorRef          error;

   success = SMJobBless(
                        kSMDomainSystemLaunchd,
                        CFSTR("DAEMON IDENTIFIER HERE"),
                        self->_authRef,
                        &error
                        );
```

Also, every time you rebuild your daemon, you have to unload the previous launch agent, with these bash commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool.plist
sudo rm /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool
```

(With your corresponding identifiers, of course)